# "I'm going home for a shower. I'm going home and pack some things, we're getting out of here."

Tags: difference, present-continuous

> I'm going home for a shower. I'm going home and pack some things, we're getting out of here.

Are these sentences actions that happening 'now' he is 'going to somewhere' or is it a 'plan'? He's planning to go home to take a shower?

How can I differentiate it from just an action like in "*Where are you? I'm going home right now.*"

Answer (score 1):

> "I'm going home for a shower"

This is arguably ambiguous as to whether it means the person is literally in the process of going home, or whether it expresses a plan / intent to do so.  I think in the vast majority of cases native speakers would interpret it to mean the latter, unless context made it obviously the former.  If a native wished to express the former meaning they would probably say something like

> "I'm on my way home for a shower"